# Creating an Array containing a Hashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create an array that contains a hash table.

Here is the code I am using.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -properties * | ? {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*,OU=Customer Service,OU=Basic,*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -NotLike "*Mercury Test Users*" -and $_.EmailAddress -Like "*@*"} 
$users.Count
$mailboxes
foreach($user in $users){
    $formatted = @{}
    $mailbox = Get-mailbox -Identity $user.Name 
    $formatted.Name = $user.Name
    $formatted.Email = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress.Local + "@" + $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress.Domain
    $mailboxes += $formatted
}
$mailboxes
```

It outputs

[image]

With the error text repeated for all apart from the first value.

I would like to have something that I could access like $mailboxes[X].Name rather than $mailboxes.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `New-Object` cmdlet will help you here, try this.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter { enabled -eq $true } -properties * | ? { $_.DistinguishedName -like "*,OU=Customer Service,OU=Basic,*" -and $_.DistinguishedName -NotLike "*Mercury Test Users*" -and $_.EmailAddress -Like "*@*" } 
$users.Count
$mailboxes = foreach ($user in $users) {
    $mailbox = Get-mailbox -Identity $user.Name 
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Name"  = $user.Name
        "Email" = $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress.Local + "@" + $mailbox.PrimarySmtpAddress.Domain
    }
}
$mailboxes
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting 
`Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null`
 on line 7 charr 9 to me it looks like the array $formatted doesn't exist 

I am using powershell 2.0 if that changes anything

Comment: I've updated my answer, does this work better?

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that got it.